# In bash, is it generally better to use process substitution or pipelines

Tags: bash

In the use-case of having the output of a singular command being consumed by only one other, is it better to use `|` ([pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines)) or `<()` ([process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution))?

Better is, of course, subjective. For my specific use case I am after performance as the primary driver, but also interested in robustness.

The `while read do done < <(cmd)` benefits I already know about and have switched over to.

I have several `var=$(cmd1|cmd2)` instances that I suspect might be better replaced as `var=$(cmd2 < <(cmd1))`.

I would like to know what specific benefits the latter case brings over the former.

Comment: Not sure about the performance aspects. But there are situations when you can't replace one with other. Worth reading [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe)

Comment: Whether robustness or performance is the goal, in both cases this is going to largely, if not fully, depend upon the task being performed.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc So do pipelines

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tl;dr: Use pipes, unless you have a convincing reason not to.

Piping and redirecting stdin from a process substitution is essentially the same thing: both will result in two processes connected by an anonymous pipe.

There are three practical differences:

#### 1.  Bash defaults to creating a fork for every stage in a pipeline.

Which is why you started looking into this in the first place:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat "$1" | while IFS= read -r last; do true; done
echo "Last line of $1 is $last"
```

This script won't work by default with a pipelines, because unlike `ksh` and `zsh`, `bash` will fork a subshell for each stage.

If you set `shopt -s lastpipe` in bash 4.2+, bash mimics the `ksh` and `zsh` behavior and works just fine.

#### 2. Bash does not wait for process substitutions to finish.

POSIX only requires a shell to wait for the last process in a pipeline, but most shells including `bash` will wait for all of them.

This makes a notable difference when you have a slow producer, like in a `/dev/random` password generator:

```
tr -cd 'a-zA-Z0-9' < /dev/random | head -c 10     # Slow?
head -c 10 < <(tr -cd 'a-zA-Z0-9' < /dev/random)  # Fast?
```

The first example will not benchmark favorably. Once `head` is satisfied and exits, `tr` will wait around for its next `write()` call to discover that the pipe is broken.

Since bash waits for both `head` and `tr` to finish, it will appear seem slower.

In the procsub version, bash only waits for `head`, and lets `tr` finish in the background.

#### 3. Bash does not currently optimize away forks for single simple commands in process substitutions.

If you invoke an external command like `sleep 1`, then the Unix process model requires that bash forks and executes the command.

Since forks are expensive, bash optimizes the cases that it can. For example, the command:

```
bash -c 'sleep 1'
```

Would naively incur two forks: one to run bash, and one to run `sleep`. However, bash can optimize it because there's no need for `bash` to stay around after `sleep` finishes, so it can instead just replace itself with `sleep` (`execve` with no `fork`). This is very similar to tail call optimization.

`( sleep 1 )` is similarly optimized, but `<( sleep 1 )` is not. The [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/subst.c?id=bc007799f0e1362100375bb95d952d28de4c62fb#n5725) does not offer a particular reason why, so it may just not have come up.

```
$ strace -f bash -c '/bin/true | /bin/true'     2>&1 | grep -c clone
2
$ strace -f bash -c '/bin/true < <(/bin/true)'  2>&1 | grep -c clone
3
```

---

Given the above you can create a benchmark favoring whichever position you want, but since the number of forks is generally much more relevant, pipes would be the best default.

And obviously, it doesn't hurt that pipes are the POSIX standard, canonical way of connecting stdin/stdout of two processes, and works equally well on all platforms.

Comment: That's really useful - thank you. Do you also agree with the conclusions here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27346/194333

Comment: Definitely. Process substitution is very useful, but as an extension of (and not a replacement for) regular pipes

Comment: @thatotherguy why do we use process substitution when sourcing vs just direct source?

Comment: @Jon It is not common to use process substitution when sourcing. This wasn't even supported until bash4.

Comment: @thatotherguy yeah I gathered, I was trying to understand _why_ you would. My thinking was that it would be functionally equivalent to executing the script but the output will be run in the current shell? Vs with execution, everything is run in the spawned shell. Maybe it requires its own question but I am having a hard time believing the question hasn't already been asked (so far I can't find it)

Comment: @Jon I imagine this could be trivially answered by seeing the `source` statement, but unfortunately I don't have access to that. If I had to guess based on your two comments, I'd guess the confusion was between `source ./foo` and `source <(./foo)` which are not equivalent so it doesn't make sense to compare them

Comment: No, it's just the difference between `source foo` and `source <(foo)` -- although thinking about `source ./foo` is sort of in the direction I was thinking the 2nd form provided would be equivalent to (although obviously not)

Comment: `source foo` and `source <(foo)` are not equivalent and can't be compared. The former runs a script file `foo` in the context of the current shell, the latter runs an arbitrary executable `foo` and evaluates its output as shell commands in the current shell (as if running `foo > file; source file`). If you want to compare process substitution to direct source, you have to compare `source <(cat foo)` to `source foo`

Comment: @thatotherguy right, so it's kind of what I was saying (or at least thinking, maybe didn't do the best job of articulating), what I wasn't thinking about is that we could do any random executable with the process substitution, so we want to get the output of `foo` to source, rather than the direct contents of `foo`